# My ReactJS frontend is importing many libraries that uses eval(); How can it be safe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval, xss, content-security-policy

I am learning to prevent XSS attacks in my frontend written in ReactJS.

I tried to use Content Security Policy Headers and configured the CSP Header to be:

```
script-src 'self'
```

Such that only script from my own origin is allowed to execute.

However, this makes my web app not able to load:

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as 
JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed 
source of script in the following Content Security Policy 
directive: "script-src 'self'".
```

Now, I am 100% sure that I never used any `eval()` function in my ReactJS code.

Doing a global search, I found that a lot of the libraries I used contain the function `eval()` in them.

These are all well-written and battle-approved standard libraries.

[image]

Does this mean that I will have to configure my CSP header to be:

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'
```

just so that my web page can load normally in the browser?

How do I ensure that all these `eval()` functions do not pose any XSS vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may not be able or willing to rewrite/replace all instances of eval and other functions counting as eval namely new Function(), setInterval(), and setTimeout(). In that case you'll need to add 'unsafe-eval' in your CSP.

With the script-src directive as 'self' 'unsafe-eval' you should no longer worry about XSS in the tradition ways as you're not allowing inline scripts and arbitrary code from other sources. The threat vector would be malicious strings processed by the application. If user input is not processed by the given libraries or you tighten relevant directives of CSP, the risk would be minimal.

See also https://web.dev/csp/#eval-too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is `setInterval()`  and `setTimeout()` counted as eval though?  Do they also have the ability to take a string and execute it as code?

Comment: Eval seems to be a generic term for functions taking input strings and executing them as code, as you can also do with setInterval() and setTimeout.